# Azure AD B2C Xamarin Forms - After Successful login OnAppearing method executing again

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

This is iOS specific issue.

I have completed all the steps suggested in document over here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/

In Andtoid it is working fine. But in iOS it is not returning back to application after successful login.

Yes, Login page is displaying properly we can enter the credentials over there but once login in successful then browser is closed but debugger not attaching back to application.

I have Eneabled Keychain access, Added Url Types in info.plist and also added below code to AppDelegate.cs

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
{
AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(url);
return true;
}
```

And on FInishLaunching event I have added below code

```
var authenticationService = DependencyService.Get();
// Default system browser
authenticationService.SetParent(null);
```

Actually I am calling SignInAsync method from OnAppearing event of view. So after successful validation OnAppearing event is firing again and it lost the previous flow.

Please let me know if I am missing something. Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: OnAppearing will be called everytime the screen appears. When you do the login, your app goes to background, so "disappears", and when login is over, it re-appears so "OnAppearing" is called again. Seems consistent to me, you might want to move your SignInAsync code elsewhere ?!

Comment: Hi @Miiite, what will be other options? I don't want to show extra screen while login?